# Circular analogue of the auto-correlation function

Tags: r

Does anyone know if a circular analogue of the auto-correlation function `acf()` exists in R or elsewhere?

Comment: Have you looked in the `circular` or `CircStats` packages?

Comment: I have. There doesn't seem to be an acf() equivalent